# How Map two entities that share the same primary key in hibernate with annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, primary-key, hibernate-mapping

I'm new to **hibernate** and I do not know how to map this simple [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss9hI.png)
using **JPA** or **Hibernate annotations**. I try to model is that a provider has a global rating and the identifier of the global rating entity is the same identifier of the provider entity (unidirectional OneToOne), in other words I want to have the **foreign key** in the entity global rating be **primary** and **foreign** at the same time, but that the provider entity also has a **foreign key** of the entity global rating. This is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with `@MapsId` annotation.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Provider{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long idProvider;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="provider")
    private GlobalRating rating;

    // Getter & Setter
}

@Entity
public class GlobalRating{

    @Id
    private long idProvider;
        
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name="idProvider")
    private Provider provider;
 
    // Getter & Setter          
}
```